# Vega: how to load data in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vega

I use Vega https://github.com/vega/vega.
That is how to load data:

```
var loader = vega.loader();
loader.load('data.json').then(function(data) {
  // do something with loaded data
}).catch(function(error) {
  // error handling here
});
```

How to load data using ASP.NET controller call or ajax request?

Comment: Are you trying to read a json file in ASP.NET controller?

Comment: Finally I'd like to read data from a database. If I can call controller method or do ajax request then I can read the data from database, format it and pass to js client.

Comment: Yes As you told - From js client perform ajax call to reach controller -> Read data from database -> format & Send it back to Js Client

Comment: The question is: how to do it in load() function: var loader = vega.loader();
loader.load(??)? i.e. how to load data from ASP.NET controller to vega?